# different stylecop rules for test projects

Tags: c#, testing, stylecop, code-inspection

I work with stylecop and find it very helpful. However i would like a different set of rules for my test projects than my normal c# class libraries.

Is this possible?

For example, I don't want my methods having an underscore in them in normal libraries but its ok in my test projects. So my IDE should alert me of rule violation in normal projects but not in test projects for such.

Follow on from this is that I would like similar as part of my msbuild tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StyleCop is configurable per project. Right-click on a test project, select StyleCop settings, and disable the underscore rule for your test project.

What you can do then is keep all your test projects in a sub-folder, e.g. test/ (on the disk, not solution folder) and move the Settings.StyleCop file up from the project folder to the test/ folder. Now you can share the one settings file between all your test projects.

Comment: Note that [this documentation](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20StyleCop%20Settings%20Across%20Projects&referringTitle=Documentation) goes into more detail.

Comment: What if I have the test project file and the original project file in the same folder? Can I still separate their configuration files somehow?

Comment: @julealgon I don't think so, you should consider reorganizing your projects if having different StyleCop settings is important to you

Comment: Update on my own comment. Now that rules can be turned on and off via `editorconfig` it _is_ possible to use whatever folder structure and still have centralized settings. Editorconfig allows for file/folder-based filters when specifying its rules.